# Load workflow in 2 aspx pages

Tags: c#, asp.net, workflow, workflow-foundation, workflow-foundation-4

I am working on an ASP .net project. I have 2 pages. In the first page i have the following code which creates a new workflow

```
           var connStr = @"Data Source=M-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=sella;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False";
        AutoResetEvent syncEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);
        var store = new SqlWorkflowInstanceStore(connStr);
        var app = new WorkflowApplication(new Activity1() { str = 4 });
        app.InstanceStore = store;

        app.Idle = delegate(WorkflowApplicationIdleEventArgs o)
        {

            syncEvent.Set();
        };

        app.Unloaded = (workflowApplicationEventArgs) =>
        {
            syncEvent.Set();
        };

        app.Run();
        syncEvent.WaitOne();

        string text = TextBox3.Text;
        app.ResumeBookmark("readText", text);
        syncEvent.WaitOne();
        app.Unload();
        syncEvent.WaitOne();
        Response.Redirect("WebForm1.aspx");
```

Then in the next page WebForm1 i am trying to reload the same workflow from the instance store in order to resume another bookmark with the following code.

```
          var connStr = @"Data Source=M-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=sella;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False";
        AutoResetEvent syncEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);
        var store = new SqlWorkflowInstanceStore(connStr);
        var app = new WorkflowApplication(new Activity1());
        app.InstanceStore = store;

        app.Idle = delegate(WorkflowApplicationIdleEventArgs o)
        {

            syncEvent.Set();
        };
        app.Completed = delegate(WorkflowApplicationCompletedEventArgs o)
        {
            syncEvent.Set();
        };

        id = new Guid(TextBox2.Text.ToString());
        app.Load(id);
        syncEvent.WaitOne();
        app.Run();
        syncEvent.WaitOne();

        string text = TextBox1.Text;
        app.ResumeBookmark("readText1", text);
        syncEvent.WaitOne();
```

But when i execute the workflow nothing happens. Does anyone have any ideas how to approach it? Thx for your time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you'll be blocking on the first WaitOne as once loaded the workflow won;t go idle until started

Does the workflow run if you remove the first wait?